# Does Reset and "Erase All Content and Settings" removes iOS updates?

Tags: ipad, settings

I want to reset and clear the iPad.

But I would like to keep the iOS updates.

[image: Erase the Content and Settings on iPad]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Factory resetting your phone only deletes the user data; the operating system and firmware will still remain the same.

That means, if your iPhone is running iOS 9.3.2 before you reset with `Erase all content and settings`, it will be running iOS 9.3.2 (minus all of your data) once it starts up again.

Comment: Yep, this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot revert the operating system. As a result, you are free to remove all content and settings and the iOS version will remain the same. Resetting all settings will also not impact the operating system.